# Commands to different terminals

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

I have two application in two different terminals launched by *gnome-terminal -e* in a bash script. Is there a way to send commands from the script only to a particular terminal?

[image]

Comment: Are we assuming the applications have a separate text interface here, rather than just flags you can pass when calling them? Or are you waiting for them to finish running then running other commands? Or what?

Comment: The applications are called with some arguments, the they are waiting for commands coming from standard input stream (implemented as cin>> in c++)

Comment: What about `rsh <other_machine> <command>`?

Comment: The applications are all on the same machine

Comment: Use named pipes so communicate processes.